# "command not found: python" each time I open the Terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm on an M1 Mac. Each time I enter a python command in Terminal, I get "command not found: python".

To fix this, I can enter `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`.

How can I use Python without having to first run the eval line above each time I open the Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` to `~/.zshrc` - here's how to do this in the Terminal:

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` to `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Could you explain how to do this? Do I create a zshrc file first by doing something [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/886132/where-is-the-zshrc-file-on-mac/1518007#1518007)? And then how do I add the eval statement to it?